# Javascript file caching issue

Tags: javascript, caching, token

I am having an incredibly weird problem that I cannot get to the root of.

I have my file: main.js that loads properly and is executed, with the code:

```
$(function() {
$('.navigation a').click(function(ev) {
    currentTab = $(this).find('.active');
    newTab =  $(this).attr('name');

    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
 });
});
```

Which works perfectly. But then if I change the code to:

```
$(function() {
$('.navigation a').click(function(ev) {
    currentTab = $(this).find('.active');
    newTab =  $(this).attr('name');
    newTab =  $(this).attr('name');
    newTab =  $(this).attr('name');
    newTab =  $(this).attr('name');
    newTab =  $(this).attr('name');

    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
 });
});
```

When I view the file directly through the browser it reverts to this:

```
$(function() {  $('.navigation a').click(function(ev) {     currentTab = $(this).find('.active');       newTab =  $(this).attr('name');     console.log(currentTab);        console.log(currentTab);        console.log(currentTab);        $('.active').removeClass('active');     $(this).addClass('active'); });});
������������������������������������������������������������������������������
```

With the console log error of:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL (Line 2)

It works perfectly, but it seems once I break a certain number of lines, it corrupts and reverts to an old cached file. From my own testing, if the file is a total of 12 lines, it works. If it is greater than 12, it breaks as shown above.

I've tried:

- CTRL + F5
- Incognito
- 3 different browsers
- 2 IDE's
- Restarted my computer
- Cleared cache, disabled cache.

Absolutely lost, any suggestions? Thank you for your time.

Comment: Something - your editor or IDE or whatever - is probably dropping some Unicode space characters into your text. Also, declare your local variables with `var`.

Comment: I've tried Sublime, Komodo, Notepad and Vim. No difference.

Comment: Do you have any minification script to minify your script files?

Comment: Well, that's got to be the problem. I don't know all the steps involved with the way you get code from your fingers to your web server, so I can't say exactly what's doing it. Cutting and pasting code from one window to another is often the culprit.

Comment: @JothimuruganB no minification scripts.

Pointy, currently running it through my VM development server. It was working perfectly, then I made a change to a line, saved and it has been broken since.

Haven't copy and pasted any code into the editor.

Comment: What happens in a "private browsing" window (which bypasses whatever cache you have)?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans exactly the same issues.

Comment: then the real question is: what happens when you rename this file, and start using the new name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the cause of the problem.

> /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

Has a line

> #EnableSendfile off

This line has to be uncommented.